# Azure resource management api retrieves only current tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, azure-rest-api

I have a Microsoft account.
I have a subscription which belongs to, say, tenant1 (AD1).
I create another active directory (say, AD2), but I don't move the current subscription to AD2.

I can create users in both active directories, make them guests for each other and login to my web api application.

Now I want to know all the tenants related to a logged in user.

For example user1 is a member of *AD1*, and a guest of *AD2, AD3*.
My web api is registered in *AD1*.

**I call https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-06-01** but it retrieves only ID of AD1,
but I expected to have an array of *AD1, AD2, AD3*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new guest user, the guest user will receive an email, the guest user must accept it from that email.

If you haven't accept it, the source will be **Invited user**. And you will not get this tenant information when you call list tenants api.
[image]

After accepting it, the source will change. Now you will be able to get this tenant in the list.

[image]

**update:**
Can you see the tenants on azure portal?

[image]

Comment: I did accept invitations, I'm able to login with guest user as well.

Comment: @amplifier Are you able to see the tenants the user belong to on Azure portal? See the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Yes I am. I see all the tenants created.

Comment: @amplifier If so, I am afraid that you need to raise a support ticket on azure portal by following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request